# PathMatch full always connecting to parameterized path even when the full path is not matching

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have routes like this

```
{
    path: ':fundHouseName',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [{
        path: RoutePaths.funds,
        component: FundsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]
},
{
    path: '',
    children: [{
        path: RoutePaths.funds,
        component: FundsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]
},
```

What I want is that this route should match with the parameterized route (the first route)

`https://localhost:4200/Kotak/funds`

and this should match with the non parameterized one (the second route)

`https://localhost:4200/funds`

But both of the routes match with the parameter one while I have put `pathMatch:'full'` on the parameter route so what my understanding is that it should not match the parameter route until the route is full that is, the route should have `:fundHouseName` part and then `funds` part, so basically the path must be a full path like this

`XYZ/funds`

Is my understanding wrong about `pathMatch`?

How can I achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{
    path: '',
    children: [{
        path: RoutePaths.funds,
        component: FundsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]
},
{
    path: ':fundHouseName',
    children: [{
        path: RoutePaths.funds,
        component: FundsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]
},]
```

Just swap the order that will fix the issue.

> Angular router will always match the first possible one, so you need to frame the list values so that the correct one is matched for all possible scenarios

https://localhost:4200/Kotak/funds -> will not match the first route since kotak is present so it will stepover to next route

https://localhost:4200/funds -> will match on the first route itself so no stepover to second route

NOTE: pathmatch full is also not necessary in this method so I removed it